# Extract ResourceName or resourceIdentifier from resourceId function in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template, azure-rm

How do i get the name / resource identifier by the resource display name in  ARM template?

I have the user group called "Developer" and unique identifier as "xxxxxxxxxxx" under the resource type "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/groups"

By the resource display name "Developer", how can i get the identifier (xxxxxxxxxxx) ?

Comment: Not sure I follow what you're after - The resourceId is a unique identifier of a resource in Azure...  can you explain what you're after a little more?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `resourceId()` function for that:

```
resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/groups', 'ApiManagementName', 'Developer')
```

Reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#resourceid

Comment: The above comment doesn't works. It just combining the subscription id and resource group like below. /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/{resourceProviderNamespace}/{resourceType}/{resourceName}.                                        
 Even for the invalid resource name it works. it doesn't gives resource identifier.

Comment: well, then you'd have to define `resource identifier`, because there is no such thing in ARM

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to identify the resource exists in ARM template by providing the resource identifier?

Comment: no, there is no way of doing this in an arm template. at least without hacks